# Contagem total de caracteres sem strlen

Tags: c, string, matriz

Preciso realizar a contagem total de caracteres presentes em uma palavra qualquer sem a função `strlen()`.

Primeiramente realizei a leitura da palavra, após utilizei um `for` para percorrer a palavra, dentro do `for` utilizei o `while` para acrescentar o meu contador enquanto `palavra` na posição `[i]` for diferente de nulo `\0`, no entanto um erro está acontecendo, o programa até abre, mas não executa nada. 
No console é reportado que estou tentando comparar um ponteiro com um inteiro, como poderia resolver isso?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
char palavra[20];
int tam=0 ,i;

printf("\n Digite uma palavra: ");
gets (palavra);

for (i=0; i < palavra ;i++)
{
    while(palavra[i] != '\0')
    {
        tam ++;
    }
}   
printf("\n %d", tam);
}
```

Comment: `i < palavra`, `i` é um inteiro e `palavra` é um ponteiro, mas mesmo arrumando isso terá problemas com o `while` que será infinito. Considerando a palavra `"abacate"`, `i` começaria em zero e o `while` irá executar enquanto `palavra[0]` é diferente de `'\0'`, que é sempre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comparação executada no for `i < palavra` não faz sentido e ira gerar um *loop* infinito e mesmo assim no seu código você não sairia do `while` nunca pois a variável `i` não esta sendo somada no `while`, uma forma de fazer é você mesmo ir somando os valores no `i` no `while` sem utilizar o `for`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char palavra[20];
    int tam=0 ,i;

    printf("\n Digite uma palavra: ");
    gets (palavra);

    i = 0;
    while(palavra[i] != '\0')
    {
        i++;
        tam ++;
    }
    printf("\n %d", tam);
}
```